# order by meta start_dato value (ACF)

Tags: rest-api

I have an issue sorting a meta date value for an event application in the WP REST API. I made a custom post type and some custom fields (acf).

What I want is the closest event (after today's date) to display first (the start_dato object), but I can't figure my way around the WP REST parameters.

Here's a link to the custom post type I made in the WP REST API: http://titomagic.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/arrangement

Comment: you can order the result of the REST request with the filter `rest_post_dispatch`.

Comment: Thanks, mmm! Like this? http://titomagic.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/arrangement?filter=rest_post_dispatch

Comment: it's a filter to use in your code https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_dispatch/

Comment: i was just thinking that it would be better to define the order in the query arguments with the filter `"rest_{$this->post_type}_query"`